# Specifying a true/false result in foreach loop

Tags: php, magento

I apologize ahead of time for the crappy question title I couldnt figure out a good way to summarize the solution Im looking for in a sentence.

Platform is Magento/PHP but the Magento part isnt really a part of this problem. Basically we have a service at checkout (just a dropdown box) for customers to select a future date for their order to ship. Ive been tasked with limiting the display of this service to only a few products.

- If an order contains one or more of a permitted product, or, several of the products that are permitted it would display the dropdown box.
- If the order contains a mix of permitted and non-permitted products obviously it would not show the dropdown box.

I created a new product attribute called "can_futureship" and set the value to True for the few products that are permitted to ship on a future date. My problem now is I cant seem to grasp the best way to single out those products.

There is a chunk of code (foreach loop) that goes through all the items in the cart and checks them for other restrictions and attributes so I know I need to put it in that loop. Especially in the cases of mixed True and False conditions. For example some pseudocode:

```
Product1 = True
Product2 = True
Product3 = True

$can_futureship_show_drop_down = false;

foreach(Items as item) {

  $product['can_futureship'] = model->getattribute('can_futureship');
  if ($product['can_futureship'] = TRUE) {
       $can_futureship_show_drop_down = true;
    }
 }
```

That was my initial line of thinking and would obviously work if all the products are true or the last product in the array is true but I need it to end up false if there any false results at all. I was also thinking that maybe I should load all results into an array and check for false results that way? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start by changing this `if ($product['can_futureship'] = TRUE) {` to `if ($product['can_futureship'] == TRUE) {` - a double `==` or `===` is required on an `if` condition.

Comment: Fred - I was just using that as some pseudocode to show my thought process. Definitely some serious syntax errors in there.

Comment: Other than the failure to use the comparison operator, you might need to think through this some more. For example, if you have two products and only one is available for future shipping, your code would show the dropdown anyway.

Comment: @jkphl That's what "comments" are for then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think the other way ;)

```
$can_ship_future = true;
foreach($products as $product) {
    if ( ! $product->canShipFuture() ) {
         $can_ship_future = false;
         break; // Don't need to check the other products
    }
}
```